# Terraform Output via Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, ansible, terraform

I'm unable to find `vpc_id` and `public_subnet.0` in a terraform my-vpc output.

Every single time when I put below command:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -e "vpc_id=$(terraform output my-vpc.vpc_id) vpc_subnet_id=$(terraform output my-vpc.public_subnets.0)" -vvv
```

But it prints terraform output `my-vpc`

```bash
-bash-4.2$ terraform output my-vpc
{
  "azs" = tolist([
    "eu-west-1a",
    "eu-west-1b",
    "eu-west-1c",
  ])
  "cgw_arns" = []
  "cgw_ids" = []
  "database_internet_gateway_route_id" = ""
  "database_ipv6_egress_route_id" = ""
  "database_nat_gateway_route_ids" = []
  "database_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "database_network_acl_id" = ""
  "database_route_table_association_ids" = [
    "rtbassoc-0c0a897cce6cbac74",
    "rtbassoc-02c2f605eb9988418",
    "rtbassoc-0b14ef189c6c39da5",
  ]
  "database_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-038a86ea7eef50de1",
  ]
  "database_subnet_arns" = [
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-0ef73bc4e91557920",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-0f044d3b21cecbca6",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-042312717d7ed4fe6",
  ]
  "database_subnet_group" = "my-vpc"
  "database_subnet_group_name" = "my-vpc"
  "database_subnets" = [
    "subnet-0ef73bc4e91557920",
    "subnet-0f044d3b21cecbca6",
    "subnet-042312717d7ed4fe6",
  ]
  "database_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([
    "10.0.21.0/24",
    "10.0.22.0/24",
    "10.0.23.0/24",
  ])
  "database_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "default_network_acl_id" = "acl-08f647113ea769f4f"
  "default_route_table_id" = "rtb-0b55d9919c1133316"
  "default_security_group_id" = "sg-050c394121822118f"
  "default_vpc_arn" = ""
  "default_vpc_cidr_block" = ""
  "default_vpc_default_network_acl_id" = ""
  "default_vpc_default_route_table_id" = ""
  "default_vpc_default_security_group_id" = ""
  "default_vpc_enable_dns_hostnames" = ""
  "default_vpc_enable_dns_support" = ""
  "default_vpc_id" = ""
  "default_vpc_instance_tenancy" = ""
  "default_vpc_main_route_table_id" = ""
  "dhcp_options_id" = ""
  "egress_only_internet_gateway_id" = ""
  "elasticache_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "elasticache_network_acl_id" = ""
  "elasticache_route_table_association_ids" = []
  "elasticache_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-0bbad3836a81d51cd",
  ]
  "elasticache_subnet_arns" = []
  "elasticache_subnet_group" = ""
  "elasticache_subnet_group_name" = ""
  "elasticache_subnets" = []
  "elasticache_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "elasticache_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "igw_arn" = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:internet-gateway/igw-006457c32d869d138"
  "igw_id" = "igw-006457c32d869d138"
  "intra_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "intra_network_acl_id" = ""
  "intra_route_table_association_ids" = []
  "intra_route_table_ids" = []
  "intra_subnet_arns" = []
  "intra_subnets" = []
  "intra_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "intra_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "name" = "my-vpc"
  "nat_ids" = [
    "eipalloc-0a8b17a3d8101a5a0",
  ]
  "nat_public_ips" = tolist([
    "18.200.43.46",
  ])
  "natgw_ids" = [
    "nat-0c1f640cfa6bc1b9c",
  ]
  "outpost_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "outpost_network_acl_id" = ""
  "outpost_subnet_arns" = []
  "outpost_subnets" = []
  "outpost_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "outpost_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "private_ipv6_egress_route_ids" = []
  "private_nat_gateway_route_ids" = [
    "r-rtb-0bbad3836a81d51cd1080289494",
  ]
  "private_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "private_network_acl_id" = ""
  "private_route_table_association_ids" = [
    "rtbassoc-046f37259950a7f95",
    "rtbassoc-0be769cfe2ebd6034",
    "rtbassoc-03dab517c9aa2789c",
  ]
  "private_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-0bbad3836a81d51cd",
  ]
  "private_subnet_arns" = [
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-038ffd52b102ad03d",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-07fff3a676d8792b7",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-09d7264428c109220",
  ]
  "private_subnets" = [
    "subnet-038ffd52b102ad03d",
    "subnet-07fff3a676d8792b7",
    "subnet-09d7264428c109220",
  ]
  "private_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([
    "10.0.11.0/24",
    "10.0.12.0/24",
    "10.0.13.0/24",
  ])
  "private_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "public_internet_gateway_ipv6_route_id" = ""
  "public_internet_gateway_route_id" = "r-rtb-095c4a905b733cb521080289494"
  "public_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "public_network_acl_id" = ""
  "public_route_table_association_ids" = [
    "rtbassoc-08b42ea2c1b00f82c",
    "rtbassoc-06d913cc918b08721",
    "rtbassoc-04437e6c3b6deea45",
  ]
  "public_route_table_ids" = [
    "rtb-095c4a905b733cb52",
  ]
  "public_subnet_arns" = [
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-08dbadd83e2dfea89",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-07b49f530d35a3899",
    "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:subnet/subnet-057153ea6183d363f",
  ]
  "public_subnets" = [
    "subnet-08dbadd83e2dfea89",
    "subnet-07b49f530d35a3899",
    "subnet-057153ea6183d363f",
  ]
  "public_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([
    "10.0.1.0/24",
    "10.0.2.0/24",
    "10.0.3.0/24",
  ])
  "public_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "redshift_network_acl_arn" = ""
  "redshift_network_acl_id" = ""
  "redshift_public_route_table_association_ids" = []
  "redshift_route_table_association_ids" = []
  "redshift_route_table_ids" = tolist([
    "rtb-0bbad3836a81d51cd",
  ])
  "redshift_subnet_arns" = []
  "redshift_subnet_group" = ""
  "redshift_subnets" = []
  "redshift_subnets_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "redshift_subnets_ipv6_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
  "this_customer_gateway" = {}
  "vgw_arn" = ""
  "vgw_id" = ""
  "vpc_arn" = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:008421212484:vpc/vpc-081b13e816e14214c"
  "vpc_cidr_block" = "10.0.0.0/16"
  "vpc_enable_dns_hostnames" = true
  "vpc_enable_dns_support" = true
  "vpc_flow_log_cloudwatch_iam_role_arn" = ""
  "vpc_flow_log_destination_arn" = ""
  "vpc_flow_log_destination_type" = "cloud-watch-logs"
  "vpc_flow_log_id" = ""
  "vpc_id" = "vpc-081b13e816e14214c"
  "vpc_instance_tenancy" = "default"
  "vpc_ipv6_association_id" = ""
  "vpc_ipv6_cidr_block" = ""
  "vpc_main_route_table_id" = "rtb-0b55d9919c1133316"
  "vpc_owner_id" = "008421212484"
  "vpc_secondary_cidr_blocks" = tolist([])
}
```

I was trying with:

- Different naming and paths.
- Jenkins user privileges.
- Destination of output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for supporting my college, we found a solution:
jq ;)

```
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -e "vpc_id=$(terraform output -json my-vpc|jq -r .vpc_id) vpc_subnet_id=$(terraform output -json my-vpc|jq -r .public_subnets[0])" -vvv
```

Answer (score 2):

Outputs are meant to be human-readable:

> The `terraform output` command by default displays in a human-readable format, which can change over time to improve clarity.

That means it's not really easy to get the values using the usual terraform syntax and you would need to use a tool like `jq` [1]. So in your example, that would have to be something like:

```bash
VPC_ID=$(terraform output -json my-vpc | jq -r '.vpc_id')
VPC_SUBNET_ID=$(terraform output -json my-vpc | jq -r '.public_subnets[0]')
```

Followed by:

```bash
ansible-playbook playbook1.yml -e vpc_id=$VPC_ID -e vpc_subnet_id=$VPC_SUBNET_ID -vvv
```

My Ansible skills are a bit rusty, and there might be better ways of doing it, but this should get you started.

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/output#use-in-automation

Comment: Alternatively could pass the TF output as an entire JSON string to a single Ansible var, and then use Jinja2 filters to parse it into a dictionary and access its kv pairs accordingly (to avoid managing `jquery` on the Jenkins agents and to more robustly parse the input), but this totally does the job too.

Comment: Oh, yes, that is a great idea Matt.